# How to handle Custom Routes dynamically in Nuxt3 at nuxt.config.ts?

Tags: nuxt.js, vuejs3, middleware, nuxtjs3, dynamic-routing

I can able to route statically using this custom routes but I need to route dynamically using the path that I get from the API.

Static Custom route from `nuxt.config.ts`

```js
hooks: {
       'pages:extend' (pages) {
         pages.push({
         name: 'Article',
         path: '/sample/content/article',
         file: resolve(__dirname, 'pages/article')
        })
         console.log(pages);
       }
  }
```

API Sample code:

```json
{
   "pageProperties":{
      "path":"/sample/content/article",
      "templateName":"article",
      "title":"Sample Title",
      "type":"content/components/page/article"
   },
  }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.